# Message view in android

Tags: android, view, message

I'm implementing an app including a feedback activity. In iOS, I use jsqmessageviewcontroller. I have searched online but failed to find a similar library in android Is there any library of displaying text messages? Like the jsqmessageviewcontroller in iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no out-of-the-box solution. You will need to implement it on your own. If you look at the tutorial here: http://adilsoomro.blogspot.in/2012/12/android-listview-with-speech-bubble.html , you will get the full source code for something similar to your iOS counterpart.

In short, you need a `ListView` with a custom views and 9patch (fancy name for PNG) to make the speech bubbles.

Have a look at http://androidlibs.org/ to find more libraries, if you need.

**Update:**
https://github.com/tuenti/SmsRadar/ :

> Read incoming and outgoing text messages using an Android application
>   across different Android SDK versions it's not trivial. If yo don't
>   want to appear as SMS application and your application has to read
>   incoming and outgoing SMSs this is your library.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! Actually it's fairly easy to implement, and the only trick is actually the 9-patch conversation bubble background！